# why some photos are not working in my android application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, background-image

I am trying to set one photo as my activity background, but it is not working and i got a message

> "unfortunately, application has stopped"

when some other photos are working absolutely fine.

Comment: it hard to give the solution without knowing what exactly your error and how you have write the code

Comment: i m trying to ask are there any conditions for using pictures as background in android applicaion

Comment: How you are setting background of your activity ?

Comment: you can use xml layout to set backgrounds

Comment: yes, android:background="@drawable/image1". i m using this code for setting background

Comment: Then what kind of error or Exception you are supposed to getting

Comment: @JohnKiran, that's what happens when you don't read the basic training. Handling images efficiently is explained there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mmmm this happens when the image size is much bigger to handle ina ndroid application, it's allocating free memory to application when starting.if the image size pixel and capacity get bigger it creating this kind of errors. you can use lower size of image to get rid of this.

or

use Picasso lib to set backgrounds when use high res or big capacity images

Comment: Thank you,  you are right it's working with less quality of same picture

Comment: Good.. Use picasso its good.if you ok with the answer make it up too

Comment: I am short of reputation to make it up. Sorry. By the way your answer is helpful and i will start using Picasso.